# Unable to add custom logging data in REVINFO in envers

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am trying to use Envers for implementing Audit trails. It's creating the audit table `Person_AUD` and entering the audit data as well. But, when I try to add custom fields that are updated by Envers, nothing happens.